# iPhone screen shots in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, screenshot, multitasking

Is it possible to take screenshots in the background? I was using UIGetScreenImage(), but in the console it outputs that your not allowed to take screenshots in the background. Any way to get this working without a jailbreak, I don't care if Apple will approve it or not, I just need it work without a jailbreak on the device. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI calls have to be on the main thread.  Why can you not just do a UIGetScreenImage() call on the main thread?

Comment: I meant taking screen shots while multi-tasking. If my app closes, I still want the screenshots to come in. I am not planning to release this on the App Store so I don't care for any illegal code, I just need it for myself but I don't want to jailbreak my development device.

Comment: Sorry, but there's no way I know of to call out of your app to trigger screenshots unless you jailbreak.  Then you could trigger the system screendump to your hearts content.  You could look up what that call would be and experiment with using it while you app is backgrounded, when it's woken by a timer or something along those lines.